# Setup email account to pipe into php script in ISPConfig

Tags: php, email, pipe

I am trying to pipe an email address into a php script in ISPConfig administration.

I read that under Email mailbox/Custom rules it could be defined.

I have tried with:

to `"|/my/script.php"`

or just

```
"|/my/script.php"
```

then I found errors in `/var/vmail/mailbox/x/.sieve.log`

```
 sieve: info: started log at Nov 27 12:58:22. main script: line 5:

 error: unknown command 'to' (only reported once at first occurrence).

 main script: error: validation failed.
```

so i guess some valid sieve script should go to Custom rules instead.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it was not possible with ISPConfig and Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I think piping the email is feature of email service provide. if he give an option to pipe the email then only u can.
i don't know exactly why this of your problem come. but i faced the same issue before due to service of email.

Comment: question is the right sieve command to pipe an email to a script. it seems that "to" is a command without any interpret